# Karp's reduction strategy

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete, np

One way to prove that a problem $X$ is NP-Complete is to pick two NP-Complete problems $Z$ and $W$ and show that ($\leq_p$ is polynomial reduction):
$$\begin{array}{rr}X \leq_p Z & (1)\\W \leq_p X&(2)\end{array}$$

The usual way to prove NP-Completeness however, is to follow Karp’s strategy which consists in proving that
$$\begin{array}{rr}X\in \textsf{NP} & (3)\\W \leq_p X&(4)\end{array}$$

I am trying to show that $(1)$ and $(3)$ are equivalents, but but I'm not sure where I can start. Can someone help me with how to do this?

Comment: HINT: What's the definition of "NP-complete"? If $X$ is in NP and $Z$ is NP-complete, can you compare $X$ and $Z$?

Answer (score 1):

$(3)\Rightarrow (1)$ should just be a consequence of the definition of $\textsf{NP}$-completeness.

For $(1)\Rightarrow (3)$, you can use the fact that there exists a function $f$, computable in polynomial time, such that $u\in X \Leftrightarrow f(u) \in Z$. Now to decide if $u\in X$, you can compute $f(u)$, and then decide nondeterministically if $f(u)\in Z$.